# Flink CEP sql restrict output

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-cep

I have a use case where I have 2 input topics in kafka.
Topic schema:
`eventName, ingestion_time(will be used as watermark), orderType, orderCountry`

Data for first topic:
`{"eventName": "orderCreated", "userId":123, "ingestionTime": "1665042169543", "orderType":"ecommerce","orderCountry": "UK"}`

Data for second topic:
`{"eventName": "orderSucess", "userId":123, "ingestionTime": "1665042189543", "orderType":"ecommerce","orderCountry": "USA"}`

I want to get all the userid for orderType,orderCountry where user does first event **but not** the second one in a window of 5 minutes for a maximum of 2 events per user for a orderType and orderCountry (i.e. upto 10 mins only).

I have union both topics data and created a view on top of it and trying to use flink cep sql to get my output, but somehow not able to figure it out.

```
SELECT *
FROM union_event_table
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
        PARTITION BY orderType,orderCountry
        ORDER BY ingestion_time
        MEASURES
            A.userId as userId
            A.orderType as orderType
            A.orderCountry AS orderCountry
        ONE ROW PER MATCH
        PATTERN (A not followed B) WITHIN INTERVAL '5' MINUTES
        DEFINE
            A As A.eventName = 'orderCreated'
            B AS B.eventName = 'orderSucess'
    )
```

First thing is not able to figure it out what to use in place of `A not followed B` in sql,  another thing is how can I restrict the output for a userid to maximum of 2 events per orderType and orderCountry, i.e. if a user doesn't perform 2nd event after 1st event in 2 consecutive windows for 5 minutes, the state of that user should be removed, so that I will not get output of that user for same orderType and orderCountry again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible using MATCH_RECOGNIZE. This could, however, be implemented with the DataStream CEP library by using its capability to send timed out patterns to a side output.

This could also be solved at a lower level by using a KeyedProcessFunction. The [long ride alerts exercise](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/long-ride-alerts) from the Apache Flink Training repo is an example of that -- you can jump straight away to [the solution](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/long-ride-alerts/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/longrides/LongRidesSolution.java) if you want.

Comment: if i remove the condition of restrict output and if I want all output for A not followed by B, will it be possible in sql ?

Comment: The WITHIN clause makes it plausible that it would work, but I don't believe it does. Without the WITHIN clause it becomes completely intractable.

Comment: does anti pattern is not available in cep, is there no syntax of A not followed by B